# gradle execute task after build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am building my project with gradle, with the following build.gradle file:

```
project('a'){
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'application'

    buildDir = 'build'

    [compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
    } 
}
```

When I input the `gradle build` command, I want gradle to execute a task after the build.

I found a `mustRunAfter` on the Internet, and I have tried a variety of ways but failed.

Please tell me if you know how.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

What you need is `finalizedBy`, see the following script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task finalize {
    doLast {
       println('finally!')
    }
}

build.finalizedBy(finalize)
```

[Here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#finalizedBy(java.lang.Object...)) are the docs.

Comment: distributions {
   main{
     contents{
       into('lib'){
       }
       into('bin'){
       }
     }
   }
 }
Using this source would like to move the jar file in the lib folder lib / test folder.

Comment: Note, this does (might) not work with  `dolast` in the task. (I assume it is because it conflicts with the implied gradle order of `finalize`.)

Comment: what does the `<<` do?

Comment: @wilmol this is an equivalent of `doLast` - now deprecated.

Comment: Thank you "a.t.".  That was the hint I needed !!

Comment: +10000 , I was reading `finalize.shouldRunAfter build`  , `finalize.mustRunAfter build`, nothing happened . Your solution works.

Comment: Doesn't work on Gradle 7.4: Could not get unknown property 'build' for root project 'foobar' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays you can use a [BuildListener](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/BuildListener.html), it just works. Below is an example written in kotlin DSL

**build.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
}

android {
    //[..]

    project.gradle.addBuildListener(object : BuildListener {
        override fun buildStarted(gradle: Gradle) {}

        override fun settingsEvaluated(settings: Settings) {}

        override fun projectsLoaded(gradle: Gradle) {}

        override fun projectsEvaluated(gradle: Gradle) {}

        override fun buildFinished(result: BuildResult) {
            
            // add what you need to do here
            println("finally!")
        }

    })
}

dependencies {
    //[...]
}
```

Comment: How do you run another task in this block? For instance `./gradlew ktlintCheck`

Comment: BuildListener.buildFinished() is deprecated and will be removed in Gradle 8.0