# Gradle: How to generate sha-256 hashes for ZIP files created by distributions plugin?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm having hard times putting together [Gradle distributions plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html) and [Checksum plugin](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-checksum).

```
task createChecksums(type: Checksum, dependsOn: distZip) {
    files = fileList("${buildDir}/distributions")
    outputDir = "${buildDir}/distributions"
    algorithm = Checksum.Algorithm.SHA256
}
```

Problems:

1. How to get a list of all files produced by the distributions plugin? The fileList() method doesn't work
2. How to set it dependent on all tasks from distributions? We have more than one and they are dynamically switched on/off by build parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution for my questions:

```
task createChecksums(type: Checksum, dependsOn: build) {
   files = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/distributions")
   outputDir = new File("${buildDir}/distributions")
   algorithm = Checksum.Algorithm.SHA256
}

build.finalizedBy(createChecksums)
```

1. fileTree() reads the directory contents
2. the whole build task can be folowed by a task by setting [finalizedBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857350/gradle-execute-task-after-build), therefore ignoring the distributions plugin
3. the outputDir expects a File object, not a String